# Annotating NER dataset

Tags: bert, named-entity-recognition, annotation

I am working on annotating a dataset for the purpose of named entity recognition.

In principle, I have seen that for multi-phrase (not single word) elements, annotations work like this (see this example below):

1. Romania (`B-CNT`)
2. United States of America (`B-CNT C-CNT C-CNT C-CNT`)

where `B-CNT` stands for "beginning-country" and `C-CNT` represents "continuing-country".

The problem that I face is that I have a case in which (not related to countries) where I need to annotate like `B-W GAP_WORD C-W C-W`.

How should I proceed with the annotation in this case?

If I do annotate like in the schema above, should I expect a `BERT`-alike entity recognition system to learn and detect that a phrase can be like `B-W GAP_WORD C-W C-W`, or do I need that "C-W" (continuation word) to be exactly after the B-W (beginning word)?

Which solution is correct of the following 2:

1. `B-W GAP_WORD C-W C-W`
2. `B-W GAP_WORD B-W C-W`

And then, in case 2, find a way to make the connection between the B-Ws (actually corresponding to the same entity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there's no perfect answer to this question.

I agree with your analysis, the two options make sense:

- The first option corresponds to the correct labeling *in theory*, in the sense that it means exactly what one wants in this case: the words of the entity don't (necessarily) appear continuously.
- The second option makes things easier for the NER system by separating the two parts of the entity. This might lead to better results in *practice*, because NER systems often make errors with the B label.

If possible I would suggest to experiment with the two options. At the stage of annotation this would mean tagging such discontinuous NEs with a special temporary tag, for example:

```
B-W GAP_WORD B_OR_C-W C-W
```

this way the special `B_OR_C-W` can be automatically replaced with either B or C depending on the selected option.